# Port forwarding to virtual machine qemu

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, iptables

I recently installed a Virtual Machine under Ubuntu 11.10, Right now, I assume, it is using NAT and its internal address is 192.168.122.88.

I have setup a web server in my virtual machine and I want to be able to access it when I go to 192.168.122.88 . However, right now it times out. When I log in to the virtual machine and try to access localhost it works.

So, for some reason, my `iptables` is blocking traffic from the host to the virtual machine (But not the other way around).

How can I allow traffic to flow from my host to my vm so I can see the webserver from the host?

I used Ubuntu Virtual Machine Manager w/KVM and libvirt.

I tried doing someting like this

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.10 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.88:80
```

with no avail. Apparently it says there is no route to host??

Answer (score 1):

'No route to host' means that the host machine doesn't have a IP address that can match the net you are trying to reach (you even don't have a default route), assure you have both nets on the host.

For example:

```
$ ip route show  
default via 192.168.1.254 dev p3p1  src 192.168.1.103  
default via 172.16.128.1 dev p3p1  
169.254.0.0/16 dev p3p1  scope link  metric 1003  
172.16.128.0/17 dev p3p1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.128.2  
192.168.1.0/24 dev p3p1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.103
```

On KVM host machines, I attach the virtual interfaces to some bridge. For example:

```
<interface type='bridge'>     
  <mac address='01:02:03:04:05:06'/>       
  <source bridge='br4'/>    
  <target dev='vnet4'/>    
  <model type='virtio'/>    
  <alias name='net0'/>    
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>    
</interface>
```

Then, I assign an IP address to the bridge on the host, and set it on up:

```
ip address add 192.168.0.1/24 dev br4    
ip link set up dev br4
```

On my virtual machine, I assign some IP address on the subnet like 192.168.0.2, then the ping should be successful between them.

```
ping 192.168.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to allow forwarded connections to the virtual machines. Try this:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -m state -d 192.168.122.0/24 --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Hope this helps.